# Access key or traverse key present inside the Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my JS object in which I want to build a logic so as to get those objects where the ResponseVariations key content/length is more than 1, but somehow getting undefined for certain objects,

```
{
"Articles":[
{
"Description":"phone  service (2 variations), Default: <span style=\"font-size: 13.3333px;\">Thanks for contacting komal.. You are not allowed any phone service, which is why it s not working for many countries.<\/span>",

    "Identifier": "3314649325744785781",
        "Publishable": true,
        "AlternateContent": null,
        "AutorewordTags": null,
        "AlternateContent2": null,
        "CoBrowsingUrl": '',
        "Content": '<span style="font-size: 13.3333px;">Thanks for contacting.. You are not allowed any phone service, which is why it s not working for many countries.</span>',
        "Notes": "",
         "ResponseVariations":[
             {
                 "CreatedBy":"rui.chen@nuance.com",
                 "CreationDate":"\/Date(1638311081000-0800)\/",
                 "LastUpdateDate":"\/Date(1638311081000-0800)\/",
                 "LastUpdatedBy":"rui.chen@nuance.com",
                 "AlternateContent":null,
                 "AlternateContent2":null,
                 "CoBrowsingUrl":"",
                 "CriterionExpression":"DEFAULT_SELECTION",
                 "CriterionName":null,
                 "Id":0,
                 "Tags":[

                 ],
                 "Text":"<span style=\"font-size: 13.3333px;\">Thanks for contacting.. You are not allowed any phone service, which is why it s not working for many countries.<\/span>"
             },
             {
                 "CreatedBy":"rui.chen@nuance.com",
                 "CreationDate":"\/Date(1638311138000-0800)\/",
                 "LastUpdateDate":"\/Date(1638311138000-0800)\/",
                 "LastUpdatedBy":"rui.chen@nuance.com",
                 "AlternateContent":null,
                 "AlternateContent2":null,
                 "CoBrowsingUrl":"",
                 "CriterionExpression":"User: internal AND Country: CA",
                 "CriterionName":"",
                 "Id":0,
                 "Tags":[

                 ],
                 "Text":"<span style=\"font-size: 13.3333px;\">ok you phone service is available in Canada.<\/span>"
             }
         ],
    Title: "phone service?"
}
}
```

I access the Articles key via : node.model.article , now in order to check the key present inside this, which is ResponseVariations, it's length , I tried to add a logic like below ;

```
const a = node.model.article.ResponseVariations;
if(a.length >1)
{
     console.log(a.Title);

}
```

But is somehow returns undefined as well, is there something minor which i am missing in this?

Comment: *"my JSON object"*: that is not JSON. It is part of a JavaScript object literal. (It even uses notation that is not compatible with JSON, like `undefined`, and starts with a key, which is not in itself valid syntax. At least braces should be placed around it.)

Comment: Your JS object notation has several issues. For one, an array does not have named keys in such notation. Please fix.

Comment: Please include a complete/valid object (the current structure is not valid) and the code you are using to try to traverse it.

Comment: The Object as per the input is correct, any suggestion to traverse through it without getting undefined tag , I tried the following as well but it didn't work to get the exact key -                                                                                                          ```if(typeof(node.model.article) !== 'undefined') ```

Comment: Based on your object added in description, your properly is `Articles` and not `article`. Secondly it is an `array` and not `object` so you need to access inner object with `index`. You can do something like this `if(node.model.Articles && node.model.Articles.length > 0 && node.model.Articles[0].ResponseVariations && node.model.Articles[0].ResponseVariations.length > 0) { // your code }`

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected multiple errors in your JSON.

Remember `Articles` is an array of objects, so you need to decide on which index you want to operate.

```js
let json = `{
   "Articles":[
      {
         "Description":"phone  service (2 variations), Default: <span style='font-size: 13.3333px;'>Thanks for contacting komal.. You are not allowed any phone service, which is why it s not working for many countries.</span>",
         "Identifier":"3314649325744785781",
         "Publishable":true,
         "AlternateContent":null,
         "AutorewordTags":null,
         "AlternateContent2":null,
         "CoBrowsingUrl":"",
         "Content":"<span style='font-size: 13.3333px;'>Thanks for contacting.. You are not allowed any phone service, which is why it s not working for many countries.</span>",
         "Notes":"",
         "ResponseVariations":[
            {
               "CreatedBy":"rui.chen@nuance.com",
               "CreationDate":"Date(1638311081000-0800)",
               "LastUpdateDate":"Date(1638311081000-0800)",
               "LastUpdatedBy":"rui.chen@nuance.com",
               "AlternateContent":null,
               "AlternateContent2":null,
               "CoBrowsingUrl":"",
               "CriterionExpression":"DEFAULT_SELECTION",
               "CriterionName":null,
               "Id":0,
               "Tags":[
                  
               ],
               "Text":"<span style='font-size: 13.3333px;'>Thanks for contacting.. You are not allowed any phone service, which is why it s not working for many countries.</span>"
            },
            {
               "CreatedBy":"rui.chen@nuance.com",
               "CreationDate":"Date(1638311138000-0800)",
               "LastUpdateDate":"Date(1638311138000-0800)",
               "LastUpdatedBy":"rui.chen@nuance.com",
               "AlternateContent":null,
               "AlternateContent2":null,
               "CoBrowsingUrl":"",
               "CriterionExpression":"User: internal AND Country: CA",
               "CriterionName":"",
               "Id":0,
               "Tags":[
                  
               ],
               "Text":"<span style='font-size: 13.3333px;'>ok you phone service is available in Canada.</span>"
            }
         ],
         "Title":"phone service?"
      }
   ]
}`;
    
const data = JSON.parse(json);
    
    
if (Array.isArray(data.Articles) && data.Articles[0].ResponseVariations?.length > 1) console.log(data.Articles[0].Title);
```